# Change "en-US" to "en"

Tags: php, multi-language, bloginfo

Hey I am trying to edit the WP theme files, and I am using `bloginfo('language')` to get the language of the page.

However, it returns me "en-US", which does not work while redirect the page. The site I am working on only accept "/?lang=en".

I have tried to use if statement to specify the solution under different situations, but it failed, it seems the theme used a complex loop method, a slightly change will make the functions does not work.

So could I ask if there is an alternative way to transfer "en-US" to "en", or get "en" directly from the browser?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using a plugin to handle the multi-language portion of the site?

Comment: @Welcher yes the site uses WPML

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to get the language of the browser do so:

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
```

If you want to redirect to `?lang=en`:

```
header("location: {$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}?lang={$lang}");
```

You should read about **[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGAUGE](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)**.

There are many ways you can *dance* with languages but you should understand some key points.

1. Chose the default language of your website (French in your case)
2. The user may be French but his OS & Browser can be in English because he wants to learn the language of trade.
3. Create a cookie that stores the selected (or default) language so that you know what content to display. `$_COOKIE["wpse_166976_lang"] = "fr"` or `$_COOKIE["wpse_166976_lang"] = $land` where `$lang = get_query_var("lang")`

To get the language with **WPML** plugin, you could use `ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE` to get the language of the page

Comment: I tried to use `<a href="<?php bloginfo('wpurl');?>/find-a-location/?lang=<?php substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);?>">` but in the site it shows me blank after `/?lang=` Do you have any idea why this cause the error?

Comment: `<?php echo substr...` or `<?= substr...`

Comment: hey echo works, but it seems it didn't find the language of the page. I change the page to French manually, but it still give me english. I am sorry I should say "get the language of the page" before. Could you solve the problem? thank you :-)

Comment: @user1888625 I've edited the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you, I use "ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE" can get the language :-)

Comment: This is broken. There are **three**-letter language codes, the first language could have a `q` value of `0`, there could be multiple languages or malicious code in that header.